# Reference lookup replace in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm looking for an approach of doing hash and replace algorithm in Oracle.

I had a customer table which had customer ID and customer phone number. I have another table which had list of reference phone number values in a table. I wanted to use these reference values and replace them consistently in the main table.

There should be a consistent masking when applying this replace logic i.e. wherever the same customer appears in a  different table, the phone number replacement should be the same.

- Main table name 1    :- CUS_PHONE_NUM
- Main table name 2    :- CUS_PHONE_NUM_2
- Reference table name :- REF_PHONE_NUMBER

I had tried below approach, but the performance is hitting very badly — for 20000 customers it took 18 minutes.  Can you please suggest a better approach to get this requirement.

```
    DROP TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM  ;
    DROP TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM2 ;
    DROP TABLE REF_PHONE_NUMBER ;

    --  Main table 1 
    CREATE TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM  (
            CUS_ID VARCHAR2(09) ,
      PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(12)    ); 

    --  Main table 2
    CREATE TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM_2  (
            CUS_ID VARCHAR2(09) ,
      PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(12)    ); 

    --  reference table 
    CREATE TABLE REF_PHONE_NUMBER  ( REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE NUMBER(12)); 


    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134321) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134322) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134323) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134324) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134325) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134326) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134327) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134328) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134329) ; 
    INSERT INTO REF_PHONE_NUMBER VALUES ( 0470134320) ; 

    TRUNCATE TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM ;
    COMMIT; 

    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795401' , 0426881030  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795402' , 0426881031  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795403' , 0426881032  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795404' , 0426881033  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795405' , 0426881034  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795406' , 0426881035  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM VALUES ( '401795407' , 0426881036  ) ; 

    TRUNCATE TABLE CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 ;
    COMMIT; 

    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 VALUES ( '401795401' , 0426881030  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 VALUES ( '401795403' , 0426881032  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 VALUES ( '401795405' , 0426881034  ) ; 
    INSERT INTO CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 VALUES ( '401795407' , 0426881036  ) ; 
    COMMIT ; 


    -- SQL1 to replace reference values for Main table 1 - CUS_PHONE_NUM

    WITH REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH AS
      (
       SELECT REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE ,
              row_number() over(order by REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE) - 1   REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH,
              count(*) over() max_buckets
         FROM REF_PHONE_NUMBER
       ),
       CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH  AS
       (select CUS_ID,
               PHONE_NUMBER
         from CUS_PHONE_NUM )

     SELECT c.*, n.* ,ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, n.max_buckets)   
       FROM CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH c
       JOIN REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH n
         ON ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, n.max_buckets) = n.REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH;



    -- SQL1 to replace reference values for Main table 2 - CUS_PHONE_NUM_2

    WITH REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH AS
      (
       SELECT REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE ,
              row_number() over(order by REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE) - 1   REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH,
              count(*) over() max_buckets
         FROM REF_PHONE_NUMBER
       ),
       CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH  AS
       (select CUS_ID,
               PHONE_NUMBER
         from CUS_PHONE_NUM_2 )

     SELECT c.*, n.* ,ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, n.max_buckets)   
       FROM CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH c
       JOIN REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH n
         ON ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, n.max_buckets) = n.REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH;
```

Comment: hi jonathan , the sql i had shared is creating a hash and replacing the values from reference table.

Comment: I'll remove my comment, but I'm none the wiser — I am missing something obvious, probably what the ORA_HASH function does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `max_bucket` outside. It changed explain plan on your test data. But I don't know how it will work on your real one. I don't know your indexes too.

```
 WITH REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH AS
      (
       SELECT REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE ,
              row_number() over(order by REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE) - 1   REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH
         FROM REF_PHONE_NUMBER
       ),
       CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH  AS
       (select CUS_ID,
               PHONE_NUMBER
         from CUS_PHONE_NUM )
   , BUCKET as
     (select count(*) max_buckets from  REF_PHONE_NUMBER) 
     SELECT c.*, n.* ,ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, b.max_buckets)   
       FROM CUS_PHONE_NUM_HASH c
       cross join BUCKET b
       JOIN REF_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH n
         ON ora_hash(PHONE_NUMBER, b.max_buckets) = n.REF_PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE_HASH
```

Maybe you can also think about hard coding `max_bucket` value. After hadcoding you can create index for that:

```
create index idx_CUS_PHONE_NUM_01 on CUS_PHONE_NUM
( ora_hash(Phone_NUmber, 255) )
```

Comment: HI dcieslak the performance had increased drastically for the method you mentioned and the performance issue is solved now. But i'm getting duplicate issue. i.e. same phone number allocated to different customers.

Comment: Is there a way where i can get unique phone numbers for each customers the lookup table had more reference values than the original customer table so i'm xpecting unique values for each customer.

Comment: I guess it's because of hash function. Multiple phone numbers can create the same hash value.  You can try to use max possible value for max_bucket parameter. The default is 4294967295. It's big enough to not have duplication but there is still a risk.

Comment: i had used the maximum number but it returned zero rows when i used the maximum number. is there a way to achieve uniqueness

Comment: The CUS_PHONE_NUMBER_HASH has to be populated with the same max_bucket size. Do you really need to use hash function? Maybe you can just use phone numbers directly. The hash function cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: M requirement was to have consistent masking across the database if a customer appears in multiple tables the customer should be mapped to same phone number.  "Maybe you can just use phone numbers directly." how can i do this ?